# php output content via if else

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a problem. I need the records to be displayed only not in these categories. But if I put `woocommerce_content();` in if, then they are not deduced anywhere, and if the else is deduced in the same rubrics. Help!

```
if( has_term( array('furniture','kitchen','furniture'), 'product_cat' )) {
} else {
     woocommerce_content();
}?>
```

Comment: Kindly, Your question is not really clear or well worded (for me)

Comment: Absolutely unclear what you want, please go read [ask].